# iOS: difference between UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification on iOS 8?

Tags: ios

On iOS 8, I found that every time I change the input language of keyboard or tap a text field to make keyboard appear, both `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` are received.

So what's the difference between this two notifications and 
what is the right thing to do in callbacks of this two notifications?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification), `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` is "posted immediately after a change in the keyboard’s frame," so it should post both after `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.

Whether you should use `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` or `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` depends on what you're trying to accomplish... If you need the notification to trigger an action just when your keyboard appears use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`; otherwise, if you need the notification to trigger the action both when the keyboard appears and disappears use `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification`.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` is posted for all changes, not just showing and hiding.  For example if the keyboard changes size - which can happen for many reasons, such as switching to a different installable keyboard, the keyboard deciding to offer a suggestion, or splitting the iPad keyboard into 2).

Note also that you can receive multiple calls to `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` for every call to `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` - ie. having been told a change **will** occur, if that change is sufficiently complex, you may be told about multiple changes that actually **did** occur.